# How can i make a new array easily?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanna make a new array consist of a name element.

```
let list = [
  [['firstName', 'Mary'],['lastName', 'Jenkins']],
  [['lastName', 'Kim']],
  [['firstName', 'Joe']]
];
```

I wanna extract the name value in this array, and return it to be like that

```
['Mary Jekins','Kim','joe'] // i want make it
```

How can I make it easy?  apparently, I ever tried recursion But I faced another difficulty.
if I pushed the element to a new array,
it going to be like that.

```
['Mary','Jekins','Kim','Joe'] // i don't want it.
```

How to treat well? I need some tips.

Comment: Define "easy" and show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: actually i wanna some tip.. not answer..

Comment: Why not use objects instead of arrays for the persons?

Comment: ohh yes.. great idea :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I'd use a `map`, and in the map callback turn those sub-arrays into objects, then build the output string from the object properties; destructuring the object gives me a convenient moment to default either name if it's missing:

```
const names = list.map(entry => {
    const {firstName = "", lastName = ""} = Object.fromEntries(entry);
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`.trim();
});
```

Live Example:

```js
let list = [
    [["firstName", "Mary"],["lastName", "Jenkins"]],
    [["lastName", "Kim"]],
    [["firstName", "Joe"]]
];

const names = list.map(entry => {
    const {firstName = "", lastName = ""} = Object.fromEntries(entry);
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`.trim();
});
console.log(names);
```

I'm using the object there just in case instead of `[["firstName", "Mary"],["lastName", "Jenkins"]]` you sometimes have `[["lastName", "Jenkins"],["firstName", "Mary"]]`.

Comment: ohh interesting too.. actually i thought template method ... but i cant using that. you give me a nice answer to me :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use map on each of the child list (here 3), and for each of the child list, map the value only and join them (or do anything else you want)

```js
let list = [
  [
    ["firstName", "Mary"],
    ["lastName", "Jenkins"],
  ],
  [["lastName", "Kim"]],
  [["firstName", "Joe"]],
];

const res = list.map((l) => l.map(([_, value]) => value).join(" "));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I don't think I'd make that assumption about the order of the sub-sub-arrays. :-)

Comment: hmm interesting. you using map method twice ? look soo good .. but i can't understand well..:) could you explain to me more?

Comment: @Loolii the outer map is for iterating the sublist, and the inner map is for iterating the list of the sub list itself. `[["firstName", "Mary"],["lastName", "Jenkins"],]` will first be turned to `["Mary", "Jenkins"]` and then joined to `"Mary Jenkins"`

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple solution where I iterate the first level by Array.map() and then for the 2nd level of iteration I simply check if the name array has name element pair or not. Since the structure is storing key value pairs in form of arrays so its safe to omit the first element in each, assuming that its either of the key.

```
let list = [
  [['firstName', 'Mary'],['lastName', 'Jenkins']],
  [['lastName', 'Kim']],
  [['firstName', 'Joe']]
];

let newList = list.map(name => {
   let n = name.length>0 ? name[0][1] : ''; //take the first name value pair
   n+=' '+(name.length>1 ? name[1][1] : ''); // append space and 2nd name value pair
   return n.trim(); //trim the full name in case we didn't have full name
});

console.log(newList);
```

https://ideone.com/KQfYDF

Comment: Don't forget to explain how your solution works! Also SO has a build in snippet creator via the `[<>]` button, no need to link to an external site.

Comment: I'm a mobile phone user so I try to keep things minimum at my end. But wait I'll try to explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
const namesArr = [];
for (let item of list) {
 const [first, second] = item;
 const [key, value] = first || ["", ""];
 const [key1, value1] = second || ["", ""];
 namesArr.push(`${value} ${value1}`);
}
console.log(namesArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this with a forEach:

```
const list = [
  [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins']],
  [['lastName', 'Kim']],
  [['firstName', 'Joe']]
];
const newList = []
list.forEach(person => {
  if (person.length == 1) {
    newList.push(person[0][1]);
  }
  if (person.length == 2) {
    newList.push(person[0][1] + ' ' + person[1][1]);
  }
});

console.log(newList)
```

But I would suggest you to use an other datastructure, if it's possible. It's more clear:

```
const list = [
  {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins'},
  {lastName: 'Kim'},
  {firstName: 'Joe'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to treat well? I need some tips.

Yes, You can use `Array#map` combined with `Array#reduce` like this

```js
let list = [ [["firstName", "Mary"],["lastName", "Jenkins"]],
             [["lastName", "Kim"]],
             [["firstName", "Joe"]]];

const names = list.map(array => 
                  array.reduce((acc, [_, value]) => acc += ` ${value}`, '').trim());
console.log(names);
```

**Output:**

```
[
  "Mary Jenkins",
  "Kim",
  "Joe"
]
```